# AngularJS doesn't work with yii2

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, yii2

I'm trying to get simple Hello World from yii2 layout.
AppAsset.php:

```
...
    public $js = [
       'js/angular.min.js',
    ];
...
```

layout/main.php:

```
...
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>" ng-app="app">
...
<body ng-contoller="ctrl">
...
    <div class="container">
        {{hello}}
...
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?=Html::jsFile('@web/js/app.js')?>
</body>
...
```

/js/app.js

```
angular.module('app', [])
       .controller('ctrl', function($scope){
            $scope.hello = 'Hello World!';
            console.log('inside ctrl');
    });

console.log('outside ctrl');
```

'outside ctrl' works fine. but block 'inside ctrl' doesn't.
Page not shows anything about {{hello}}.
Where I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you loading the app js outside the AppAsset? Should be there too in order to work.

If you dont want to do that at lest load de app js above the endbody function.

Comment: app.js inside the AppAsset works same. I did it before. Loading before endbody function gives a error. I can't call angular before I load it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just include your `app.js` file in `AppAsset.php` like as

```
public $js = [
    'js/angular.min.js',
    'js/app.js',
];
```

its working for me.